# shell scripts convert to perl scripts?

Tags: perl

i have shell command like?

`sort -k 1 -u  ../same_files/put_$2 > ../same_files/p1_$2`.

i want to convert this command into perl scripts it is posible to convert

Comment: While lacking in detail I don't think this should've been closed, especially not for a new user and without comment/explanation.

Comment: Perl scripts don't *display* anything, so I thing it's not an answerable question.

Answer (score 1):

You could [create a trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html) on the table `ON INSERT OR UPDATE`. Let it fire `FOR EACH STATEMENT`.

In the trigger execute [`NOTIFY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-notify.html) for data that matches your criteria and have the client application [`LISTEN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-listen.html). The client then executes a `SELECT` to fetch the data it wants.
`LISTEN`/`NOTIFY` is the way to go to trigger events outside of PostgreSQL.

Comment: @kunalwani I agree with Erwin's answer; `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` are the way to go. Additionally, since it sounds like this is a web page, you will need to use one of the standard push techniques to allow you to update a web page that's already been delivered to the client. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology . Look into using the WebSockets API or long-polling, in both cases with client-side JavaScript to get JSON or XML updates from your perl script when it receives a NOTIFY message and use the JSON or XML data to update the page's DOM with the new data.